# JQuery Sortable - Can't drag an element out of sortable once dropped inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need some help using JQueryUI Sortables.  I am trying to make a word game 
similar to magnetic word tiles you've seen for your refrigerator.  I have 
experimented with helper option `'clone'` and `'original'` and even a helper function.
I've also tried enabling/disabling sortables dynamically.  What I am trying to do is
drag the tiles into the center div, where you can place them in sentence 
order.  I can drag tiles around and drop them anywhere in the play field, but
when they are dropped in the build line, they are inserted into the sentence
or appended to the end.  But then I am unable to drag the tiles out of the
build area.  I can move them within the build area, but I can't drag them
out.  I have a minimal code showing the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RufusVS/3txa6dzn/latest/).  I can make all the
areas sortables, but then the tiles sort in all divs, which is not what
I need.

Can anyone tell me why the tiles can't be dragged out of the build area
and how to remedy this?  I have a feeling it involves re-parenting the
dragging tile, but I'm not sure how to do that, or if there's some data
structures built internally by JQueryUI that I need to get to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually care about your elements:

```
    function bind_drag(){
    $(".tile-drop span").draggable({
    containment : '.container',
    connectToSortable : '#build-area'
  });
}

function bind_sort(){
    $("#build-area").sortable({
            receive : function( event, ui ){
      ui.item.draggable()
        ui.item.draggable('disable');


     }
  });
}


$(function(){
    bind_sort();
  bind_drag();
var leftButtonDown;
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
   if(e.which === 1) leftButtonDown = true;
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
   if(e.which === 1) leftButtonDown = false;
});
  $(".tile-drop").droppable({
    accept : '#build-area span',
     containment: ".container",
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
       if (leftButtonDown) { return; } //for duplicates bug
       if(ui.draggable.hasClass('ui-sortable-helper')) {
          $(ui.draggable).clone(true).remove().appendTo(this);
          $(ui.draggable).remove()
          bind_drag();
          bind_sort();
        }
    }
  });

});
```

Here is some [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khwbvq6y/)

Also I would like to point out that there is currently a bug with `droppable` drop event, which might result in creation of duplicates: [bug](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6259)

EDIT: Updated fiddle and code to fix the duplicate bug

Comment: I ran your fiddle, and as soon as I tried to drag the tile past the sortable div, it created a duplicate of the tile .  (Either direction from bottom to top or top to bottom).

Comment: Edited to solve that. When testing for the first time it wasn't creating duplicates each time.

Comment: I can drag them out of the sortable, but they won't drop.  They snap back into the sortable on release.

Comment: Edited again, totally forgot we turn off draggable in receive event of sortable

Comment: I think you've got it!  Thanks!